# Как подсветить средний рейтинг на основе оценок пользователей?

Tags: css, css3

Всем привет. Использую библиотеку Starability.css, где юзер может кликнуть на звездочку, поставив оценку продукту/сервису.
https://github.com/LunarLogic/starability
У меня уже есть средний рейтинг на основе основе оценок пользователей, например 3.45 и мне нужно при загрузке страницы подсветить 3.5 звезды.
Как это сделать? В документации не нашел ответа. Или может подскажите аналогичную библиотеку, где это можно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 30%,rgba(214,214,214,1) 30%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

вот пример решения, через градиент, вместо % ставьте свой процент.